Custom Navigation in a ngb Range date picker in Angular
I have a range datepicker which i am trying to clone and this is the link of datepicker which is used in a website:
https://mengxiong10.github.io/vue2-datepicker/index.html#Range
[]
(https://i.sstatic.net/l2ydmV9F.png)
I want to use custom months and year navigation. which i created and implemented but the real problem is that my range datepicker screens are by default binded to each other and if i try to navigate one screen the other screen will also navigate. I want to change my days template of both screens separately based on my separate variables for FromDate and ToDate.
This is what i tried:
ts logic code:
constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar, private renderer: Renderer2, private backendService: BackendService, private http: HttpClient,) {

    this.fromDate = this.calendar.getToday();
    this.toDate = this.calendar.getNext(this.fromDate, 'd', 8);
    this.updateInputValue();
    const today = this.calendar.getToday();
    this.fromYear = today.year;
    this.fromMonth = today.month;
    this.toYear = today.year;
    this.toMonth = today.month + 1 > 12 ? 1 : today.month + 1;
    this.startDate = { year: today.year, month: today.month, day: today.day };
    this.maxDate = {
      year: this.fromYear,
      month: this.fromMonth,
      day: today.day
    };
  }

prevMonth(range: 'from' | 'to') {
    if (range === 'from') {
      this.fromMonth=this.fromMonth === 1 ? 12 : this.fromMonth - 1;
    } else if (range === 'to') {
      if(this.toMonth>this.fromMonth+1 && this.fromMonth<this.toMonth){
        this.toMonth=this.toMonth === 1 ? 12 : this.toMonth - 1;
      }
      else if(this.toMonth===this.fromMonth && this.fromYear !== this.toYear){
        this.fromMonth=this.fromMonth === 1 ? 12 : this.fromMonth - 1;
      }else if(this.fromYear === this.toYear){
        this.toMonth=this.toMonth === 1 ? 12 : this.toMonth - 1;
        this.fromMonth=this.fromMonth === 1 ? 12 : this.fromMonth - 1;
      }else{
        this.toMonth=this.toMonth === 1 ? 12 : this.toMonth - 1;
      }
    }
    if(this.fromMonth === 12) this.fromYear--
    if(this.toMonth === 12) this.toYear--
    this.fromDate={month:this.fromMonth,year:this.fromYear}
    this.toDate={month:this.toMonth,year:this.toYear}
  }

  nextMonth(range: 'from' | 'to') {
    if (range === 'from') {
      if(this.fromMonth+1<this.toMonth){
        this.fromMonth=this.fromMonth === 12 ? 1 : this.fromMonth + 1;
      }
      else if(this.toMonth+1===this.fromMonth && this.fromYear === this.toYear){
        this.toMonth=this.toMonth === 12 ? 1 : this.toMonth + 1;
      }else{
        this.toMonth=this.toMonth === 12 ? 1 : this.toMonth + 1;
        this.fromMonth=this.fromMonth === 12 ? 1 : this.fromMonth + 1;
      }
    } else if (range === 'to') {
      this.toMonth = this.toMonth === 12 ? 1 : this.toMonth + 1;
    }
    if (this.toMonth === 1) this.toYear++;
    if(this.fromMonth === 1) this.fromYear++;
  }

  prevYear(range: 'from' | 'to') {
    if (range === 'from') {
      this.fromYear--;
      this.toYear--
    } else if (range === 'to') {
      this.toYear--;
      this.fromYear--
    }

  }

  nextYear(range: 'from' | 'to') {
    if (range === 'from') {
      this.fromYear++;
      this.toYear++
    } else if (range === 'to') {
      this.toYear++;
      this.fromYear++
    }
  }

onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    console.log(date)

    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date.after(this.fromDate)) {
      this.toDate = date;
      this.updateInputValue();
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
      this.formattedRange = '';
    }
  }

HTML code:
<ngb-datepicker #dp [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t" (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)"
                    class="ngb-dp-container" [startDate]="startDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" outsideDays="visible"
                    ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                    <ng-template #t let-date let-focused="focused" let-currentMonth="currentMonth">
                      <span class="custom-day" [class.focused]="focused" [class.range]="isRange(date)"
                        [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)" (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
                        (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
                        {{ date.day }}
                      </span>
                    </ng-template>
                  </ngb-datepicker>

This is changing my months text based on logic properly but not changing the days template which i want. The issue is that I researched that the datepicker can be navigated by their own built-in function navigateTo() which requires a parameter that is of ngbDate type but this function only navigates the from screen. If anyone knows this solution. give it a try.
